# Total items in a list

Tags: r, indexing

Can anyone tell me why I do have only 1895 elements instead of 1896(79 days X 24 hours)?

```
 time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 01:00"),
                    to = as.POSIXct("2017-03-21 24:00"), by = "hour")

 length(time_index)
# >[1] 1895
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

daylight saving ?

```
time_index[1655:1660]

[1] "2017-03-11 23:00:00 EST" "2017-03-12 00:00:00 EST"
[3] "2017-03-12 01:00:00 EST" "2017-03-12 03:00:00 EDT"
[5] "2017-03-12 04:00:00 EDT" "2017-03-12 05:00:00 EDT"
```

to stop it from happening one must choose a time zone where there is no daylight saving,  here is an example

```
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 01:00",tz = 'UTC'),
                 to = as.POSIXct("2017-03-21 24:00", tz = 'UTC'), 
                  by = "hour")


length(time_index)
[1] 1896
```

Comment: Do you know how to stop it?

Comment: time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2017-01-02 01:00", tz = 'UTC'), to = as.POSIXct("2017-03-22 00:00", tz = 'UTC'), by = "hour")

Comment: I edited the answer to answer the question in your comment, look above.